# If $m^*(E)=0$ Then $E$ Is Measurable

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Prove: If $m^*(E)=0$ Then $E$ Is Measurable

If $A\subset E$ then $A\cap E\subseteq E$ and by the monotonicity of the outer measure $$m^*(A\cap E)\leq m^*(E)=0$$

On the other hand $A\cap E^C\subseteq A$ then by the monotonicity of the outer measure $$m^*(A\cap E^C)\leq m^*(A)$$

Using the sufficient condition of Cartheodory: $E$ is measurable if for all $A$,    $m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^C)$

We have:

$m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap E^C)+0=m^*(A\cap E^C)+m^*(A\cap E)$

Why in the first place can we assume that $A\subset E$? shouldn't it hold for any $A$?

Comment: If $A \subset E$ then $A \cap E^c = \varnothing$ and $A \cap E = A$.

Comment: So we must assume that $E\subset A$? if so why can we do it?

Comment: @newhere Observe that your argument is valid even when $A$ is any arbitrary set.

Comment: @ThomasShelby How can it be? if I do not know anything regarding the "relation" between $A$ and $E$, how can I say that $A\cap E\subset E$ or $A\cap E^C\subset A$?

Comment: @newhere Really? What's $A\cap E$? $A\cap E$ contains all elements that are in both $A$ and $E$. It's definitely a subset of both $A$ and $E$.